# Problem with strtok only saving the first token

Tags: c

I was having a problem with my function yesterday that turned out to be a simple fix, and now I am have a different issue with it that is baffling me. The function is a tokenizer:

```
void tokenizer(FILE *file, struct Set *set) {
     int nbytes = 100;
     int bytesread;
     char *buffer;
     char *token;
     buffer = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);
     while((bytesread = getLine(&buffer,&nbytes,file)) != -1) {
          token = strtok(buffer," ");
          while(token != NULL) {
              add(set,token);
              token = strtok(NULL," ");
          }
     }
}
```

I know that the input(a text file) is getting broken into tokens correctly because in the second while loop I can add printf("%s",token) to display each token. However, the problem is with add. It is only adding the first token to my list, but at the same time still breaks every token down correctly. For example, if my input text was "blah herp derp" I would get

token = blah

token = herp

token = derp

but the list would only contain the first token, blah. I don't believe that the problem is with add because it works on its own, ie I could use

```
add(set,"blah");
add(set,"herp");
add(set,"derp");
```

and the result will be a list that contains all three words.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you post the code for `add(set, token)` method?

Comment: `buffer = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);` does not need the cast and you never free the associated memory :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` returns a pointer into the string buffer.  You need to `strdup()` that string and add the result to your tree instead.  Don't forget to `free()` it when you clean up the tree.

Comment: `strdup` is not guaranteed to exist on all C (C89 or C99) implementations. It is in POSIX though

Comment: I'm still new to C, so does that mean that I should generally avoid using strdup() or is it safe to use? The program will only be run on my machine, if that matters.

Comment: I'd just keep it in mind.  If you find yourself needing it on a system that doesn't have it, it's easy enough to reproduce, just `malloc()` enough space for the string and its `\0` terminator, copy the string into it, and return it.

Comment: You're ok to use it, as long as you understand the implications. You may want to use `malloc` and `strcpy` (instead of `strdup`) a few times to see how it's done when `strdup` is not available :)